# C++ preprocessor--join arguments

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to make the C++ preprocessor join arguments with a joiner token?

I've learned that I can do:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/cat.hpp>
#define arg1 foo
#define arg2 bar
#define arg3 baz
BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT((arg1)(_)(arg2)(_)(arg3))
```

to get `foo_bar_baz`.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to do it for without the repeated explicit  joiner
   characters (`(_)`) and for an argument list of variadic length?
2. Is it necessary to pass the arguments like so:

   ```
   (arg1)(arg2)(arg3)
   ```

   Can I wrap it in another macro that'll allow me to pass argument  normally, i.e.?:

   ```
   arg1, arg2, arg3
   ```

Comment: What about `##` as glue without the parentheses and the joiner characters.

Comment: Something like the [`##` preprocessor operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#.23_and_.23.23_operators)?

Comment: I forgot to mention. I really need this to work with variadic arguments. (`#define COMPOSE(...)`)  The `BOOST_PP_SEQ_CAT` macro works with arbitrarily long lists. I just don't know how to insert the joiner character into the concatenation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/fold_left.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define OP(s, state, x) BOOST_PP_CAT(state, BOOST_PP_CAT(_, x))
#define COMPOSE(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(OP, BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)), BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))) 

#define arg1 foo
#define arg2 bar
#define arg3 baz

COMPOSE(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: I get errors when I feed this to `cpp`: `m.cc:12:1: error: macro "BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given COMPOSE(arg1, arg2, arg3) ^ m.cc:12:1: error: macro "BOOST_PP_SEQ_ELEM_III" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given`

Comment: @PSkocik try add `-DBOOST_PP_VARIADICS` option.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define COMPOSE(prefix,name) prefix##_##name


int main() {
    int COMPOSE(first,par);

    first_par = 1;

    return first_par;
}
```