# C++ nested namespaces with a macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

This questions is based on

- [C++ namespaces advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713698/c-namespaces-advice)
  and
- [C++ preprocessor--join arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076419/c-preprocessor-join-arguments/31077063?noredirect=1#comment50172943_31077063)

I would like to emulate

```
namespace foo::bar::baz {
```

with a macro before C++17 arrives.

I was thinking in the lines of:

```
#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#include <boost/preprocessor/cat.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/fold_left.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>

#define OP(s, state, x) BOOST_PP_CAT(state, BOOST_PP_CAT( { namespace, x )) {
#define NS(...) namespace BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(OP, BOOST_PP_SEQ_HEAD(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)), BOOST_PP_SEQ_TAIL(BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))) 

NS(foo, bar, baz)
```

Based on the second link, but this gives me:

```
namespace foo { namespacebar { namespacebaz {
```

How do I add a space between `namespace` and the identifiers?

**Edit:**

If you can make a macro so that `ns(foo::bar::baz)` expands to `namespace foo { namespace bar { namespace baz {`, even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it much simpler with `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`:

```
#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each.hpp>

#define OP(s, state, x) namespace x {
#define NS(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(OP, , BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))

NS(foo, bar, baz)
```

This expands to

```
namespace foo { namespace bar { namespace baz {
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done much simpler:

```
#define OP(s, state, x) state namespace x {
#define NS(...) BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOLD_LEFT(OP, , BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__))
```

You don't have to treat the first namespace separately, and this allows you not to write `namespace` in the `NS` macro itself.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a38a12aee9aa2f9)